# Background of items change incorrectly. Log show correct values. How to fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add a change of the item background color in the adapter recyclerview after selecting the product through multi select, however, after selecting the second and subsequent products, the background color changes incorrectly. The logs show correctly selected products, however the background changes randomly for different products from recyclerview. After disabling the multiselect and simultaneously clearing the list of selected products, the background of randomly selected items continues to change.

...

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        ...

        if (dayOfNotification.after(expirationDateDt))
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.background_expired_products));
        if (multiSelectList.contains(productList.get(position))) {
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.background_product_selected));
            Log.d(String.valueOf(productList.get(position).getId()), productList.get(position).getName());
        }
```

...

I want to change background colors of only selected products.

Comment: It's solved. Solution is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your condition in `onBindViewHolder` method, you have to set background `if-else` both cases. Check here...

```
if (dayOfNotification.after(expirationDateDt)){
             viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.background_expired_products));
    }
else{
  viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.background_not_expired_products));
          //for not expired item color as background_not_expired_products
 }
if (multiSelectList.contains(productList.get(position))) {
                viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.background_product_selected));
 Log.d(String.valueOf(productList.get(position).getId()), productList.get(position).getName());
            }
else{
    viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.background_product_not_selected));
    //say background_product_not_selected as your color for not selected item

    }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I spent whole day on this problem. Really really thank you. Problem was solved!